# Marketing Cloud Authorization code should be generated automatically whenever it is expired

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, rest-api, refresh-token

I was able to generate access token using this link 
[Access Token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm#!) .

Now I'm making a Restful API call using this access token to MC and here is the class

```
Http h = new Http();  
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    String body = '{ "From": {
    "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
    "Name": "Code@"
,
"To": {
    "Address": "example@example.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
    "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Region": "West",
            "City": "Indianapolis",
            "State": "IN"
        }
    }
},
"Options": {
    "RequestType": "ASYNC"
}}}';      
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:****/send');
    String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer 6z5jgLtjQj4pYnMTPrsnWkm2';
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('Fulfillment service returned '+ res.getBody());

    if (res.getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.debug('Error from ' + req.getEndpoint() + ' : ' + res.getStatusCode() + ' ' + res.getStatus());
    } else{
        System.debug('Success!');
    }
```

Now for every hour I cant go and hard code the value for Access Token. How can I make it dynamic? Also make can I store the client id and secret in a configurable place so that it can be more generic.

Answer (score 0):

There is a RefreshToken option , but this only works once, so subsquent RefreshToken calls will not be made.

To circumvent, this, I would advice trying

```
if (res.getStatusCode() == 403) , request the token again
```

Comment: By keeping that condition the next step is how can I pass the generated access token dynamically